# Django pre-populated form that updates record on submit

Tags: django, forms, model

model:

```
class locations(models.Model):#table
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='Joes quick stop', unique=True)
    shop_code = models.CharField(max_length=5,default='AB005',unique=True)
    manager = models.ManyToManyField(users)
    ast_manager = models.ManyToManyField(users, blank=True, related_name='ast_mng')
    sales_manager = models.ManyToManyField(users, blank=True, related_name='sales_mng')
```

forms:

```
class locations(models.Model):
   Name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='Joes quick stop', unique=True)
   shop_code = models.CharField(max_length=5,default='AB005',unique=True)
   manager = models.ManyToManyField(users)
   ast_manager = models.ManyToManyField(users, blank=True, related_name='ast_mng')
   sales_manager = models.ManyToManyField(users, blank=True, related_name='sales_mng')

class locationsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = locations
```

Views

```
def locations(request):
    locations = locations.objects.values().filter(id=request.session['location'])
    data=locations[0]
    if request.method == 'GET':
            if request.session['Manager']== True:
                form = locationsForm(initial=data)
            context = {'locations': locations, 'form': form}
            return render(request, 'locations/locations.html', context)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
            form=locationsForm(request.POST, instance=data)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd=form.cleaned_data
                form.save()
                form = locationsForm()
                locations= locations.objects.values().filter(id=request.session['depot'])
                context = {'locations': locations}
                return render(request, 'locations/locations.html', context)
            else:
                context = {'locations': locations, 'form': form}
                return render(request, 'locations/locations.html', context)
```

I am trying to display a form that is populated with the relevant data but the user can change and then save/update the form. The above code does a good job of displaying the form with the relevant data but when the user tries to submit it the system tries to save a new record instead of updating the old and fails. I never get past `if form.is_valid():`

Comment: What are the errors on the form? You can view them your template with ```{{ form.errors }}```

Comment: yes. the errors are "locations with this Name already exists." every field that requires unique values shows that error. that is why i figure it is trying to create a new record instead of update the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are converting your `locations` objects into a list of dictionaries. And then passing a dictionary into the form as `instance`.

This is happening because you are calling the `.values()` method on the queryset. That method returns a special `ValuesQuerySet` which basically looks like a list of dictionaries. Not a list of `locations` objects.

The `instance` parameter on the form needs to be an object, not a dictionary. So just simply remove the `.values()` calls, and it should work. Like this:

```
def locations(request):
    locations = locations.objects.filter(id=request.session['location'])
    first_location=locations[0]
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.session['Manager']== True:
            form = locationsForm(instance=first_location)
        context = {'locations': locations, 'form': form}
        return render(request, 'locations/locations.html', context)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form=locationsForm(request.POST, instance=first_location)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd=form.cleaned_data
            form.save()
            form = locationsForm()
            locations= locations.objects.values().filter(id=request.session['depot'])
            context = {'locations': locations}
            return render(request, 'locations/locations.html', context)
        else:
            context = {'locations': locations, 'form': form}
            return render(request, 'locations/locations.html', context)
```